# there is extra hexadecimal number in the first of char* variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, char

I have this piece of code:

```
num = sshObj->exec_ssh_command("systemctl list-units --state active | grep service | wc -l");
active = std::stoi(num);
for (int i = 0; i < active; i++)
{
     std::string str = "systemctl list-units --state active | grep service | sed -s -n " ;
     char* command = nullptr;
     command = new char[str.size() + 1];
     strcpy(command, str.c_str());
}
```

when I debug it, this is content of `command` :

```
0x555555773b90 "systemctl list-units --state active | grep service | sed -s -n "
```

and obviously I can't use it. why is this like that? what should I do?

Comment: That's the value of `command`, which is a pointer. The string is displayed because you probably want to see it but don't want to manually look in memory at that address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`command` is a `char *`. Most likely the debugger shows you the address it's pointing to. It also treats `char *` as null-terminated string and shows it's content enclosed in quotation marks.